# count query in mysql if where condition match then show count otherwise zero

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables

```
1.stages
Sr No   Stages
2   A
7   B
12  C
17  D
22  E
27  F
2.salesdetiail
Stage   Sale    Product
A   2   xyz
B   1   Yzw
```

I want result

```
Stages  Sum(sale)
A   2
B   1
C   0
D   0
E   0
F   0
```

I tried all possible solutions but failed.Can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: show us your best possible one, so we know for the record, as you say it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below using a `LEFT JOIN`

```
select s.stages,
case when sd.sale is not null then sd.sale else 0 end as sale
from stages s left join salesdetail sd on s.stages = sd.stages;
```

Answer (score 1):

try below query-

```
SELECT s.stages, SUM(IF sd.sale IS NULL,0,sd.sale) AS sale 
FROM stages s LEFT JOIN salesdetail sd ON s.stages = sd.stages
Group by s.stages;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select s.stages,
SUM(case when sd.sale is not null then sd.sale else 0 end) as sale
from stages s left join salesdetail sd on s.stages = sd.stages
group by s.stages;
```

Hope it solved your problem